# How to limit certain char appearing in regex

Tags: python, regex

I know the title might be unclear, so I am going to describe my question more specifically.

Here are two strings:

1. 'fund assets'
2. 'fund seeks to achieve its investment objective by investing at least 80% of its total assets'

My target is the first string, so I use this regex code to get it:

```
r'fund+.+asset+'
```

The reason I use '.+' between the 'fund+' and 'asset+' is because there are other cases might have extra words between 'fund' and 'asset', such as 'fund total asset'. So I have to use '.+' to make sure I can get all possible target.

However, the second string, which will also be caught, is obviously not my target. So I want to limit the char amount between 'fund' and 'asset'.

The pseudo code is like this:

```
r'fund+(.+<=6)asset+'
```

So I limit the amount of characters between 'fund' and 'asset' should not more than 6.

Can regex do this? Thank for all your help! :)

Comment: `fund .{0,6} asset` this will be the simplest one I guess. Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/xK6dZ5/1)

Comment: Use 2 seperate regexes, first to find **fund..asset** store this in temporary variable, then use second regexp, or simply string truncate to remove 'asset'.

Comment: Do you want the word in between `fund` and `asset` to be of `6` letters or count the spaces in those 6 characters too ?

Comment: @noob You definitely resolve my problem! Thank you very much! I only want to make sure there are not more than 6 char between fund and asset!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the number of repetitions with [curly braces](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `{m,n}`
>   Causes the resulting RE to *match from m to n repetitions* of the preceding RE, attempting to match as many repetitions as possible. For example, `a{3,5}` will match from 3 to 5 'a' characters. Omitting m specifies a lower bound of zero, and omitting n specifies an infinite upper bound. As an example, `a{4,}b` will match aaaab or a thousand 'a' characters followed by a b, but not aaab. The comma may not be omitted or the modifier would be confused with the previously described form.

```
fund.{1,7}assets
```

Matches the `fund assets` and `fund total assets` but doesn't match `fund seeks to achieve its investment objective by investing at least 80% of its total assets`:

```
>>> re.search(r'fund.{1,7}assets', 'fund assets')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x107951098>
>>> re.search(r'fund.{1,7}assets', 'fund total assets')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x107951030>
>>> re.search(r'fund.{1,7}assets', 'fund seeks to achieve its investment objective by investing at least 80% of its total assets')
>>>
```

`7` is used here to make it work for your `fund total assets` sample - `total` length is 5 characters plus two spaces around the word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`{}` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
r'fund.{1,8}assets'
```

which will match 1 to 8 arbitrary characters between "fund" and "assets".

Comment: Sir, this really helps. Thank you. :)